# Ruby on Rails - Preserve radio button selected on edit view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form to create and a form to edit some information on my site. In the creation form, the user can select some radio buttons, such as "Yes" or "No", and in my database these fields are `Boolean` (true or false).

In my form edition, how can I preserve the selected radio button? Currently, if the user selects any of the options, the edit view does not preserve this information and shows only the blank radio buttons.

edit.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag guide_dog_form_path(@guidedoguser), method: "put" do %>
  <%= radio_button_tag :work, @guidedoguser.work %>
<% end %>
```

controller.rb

```
class GuideDogFormsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @contact = GuideDogForm.new(params[:contact])
    if @contact.save
      GuideDogMailer.delay_for(10.seconds, retry: true).create(@contact)
      render nothing: true, status: 200
    else
      render nothing: true, status: 400
    end
  end

  def edit
    @guidedoguser = GuideDogForm.where(rg: params[:rg]).first
  end

  def update
    @guidedoguser = GuideDogForm.where(rg: params[:rg]).first
    if @guidedoguser.update(work: params[:work])
      redirect_to guide_dog_form_path(@guidedoguser)
    else 
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

end
```

How can I show the two options in radio buttons (Yes or No) and preserve the options chosen on create?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need two separate forms for this. You can do it with just one, and by using form_for (https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) instead of form_tag. When you have an a model to operate on, you should use form_for. form_tag is for forms without backing models. In the same vein, radio_button_tag is when you don't have a backing model, and radio_button (https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/radio_button) is when you do. Since you have a model, you should go the form_tag route. I suggest changing this around to be(assuming you have a 'work' attribute on your GuideDogForm model):

edit.html.erb (you can copy and paste this in to new.html.erb and it should work like you expect for new records)

```
<%= form_for @guidedoguser do do |f| %>
  <%= f.radio_button :work %>
<% end %>
```

controller:

```
class GuideDogFormsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @guidedoguser = GuideDogForm.new
  end

  def create
    @guidedoguser = GuideDogForm.new(guide_dog_params)
    if @guidedoguser.save
      GuideDogMailer.delay_for(10.seconds, retry: true).create(@guidedoguser)
      render nothing: true, status: 200
    else
      render nothing: true, status: 400
    end
  end

  def edit
    @guidedoguser = GuideDogForm.where(rg: params[:rg]).first
  end

  def update
    @guidedoguser = GuideDogForm.where(rg: params[:rg]).first
    if @guidedoguser.update_attributes(guide_dog_params)
      redirect_to guide_dog_form_path(@guidedoguser)
    else 
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

  def guide_dog_params
    # note if you have more fields you want to persist in your model from your form, you will
    # need to add them here after :work
    params.require(:guide_dog_form).permit(:work)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks @bkimble. This should work in specific Rails version? I tried but a receive the erro "undefined method `radio_button_tag' for". What it can be? I use Rails 4.1.5

Comment: Sorry I had a typo in the original post - it should be f.radio_button . I updated my answer!

Comment: Your first paragraph (`#update`/`#update_column`) isn't exactly correct. Using `#update` is preferred most of the time since `#update_column` updates the attribute directly in the database. Skipping Rails validations and callbacks. See the [`#update_columns`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_columns) documentation.

Comment: You're right . I was looking at AR::Base.update which expects an ID and the hash.. Fixing my answer.